# Valid date time python

Tags: python, datetime

Given an input of integers. Is there any way to check if the date time is possible using the given integers. I want to generate all such dates and return maximum one. The code I wrote contains too many if-else cases and is the only for valid time constraints.

```
import random
sortime = []
hr1 = []
hr2 = []
min1 = []
min2 = []
sec1 = []
sec2 = []
index1 = 0
index2 = 0
index3 = 0
index4 = 0
index5 = 0
index6 = 0

ztn = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

anysix = [random.randint(0,9) for x in range(6)]
print(anysix)

def index_clk(any_six, index_pos, index, timelist, y):
    global index1

    for x in any_six:

        if x <= y:
            index_pos.append(x)

    if index_pos == []:
        print("no clock time possible")

    index = max(index_pos)
    index1 = index

    timelist.append(index)
    print(timelist)

    any_six.remove(index)
    print(any_six)

    index = index1

print(index_clk(any_six = anysix, index_pos = hr1, index = index1, timelist = sortime, y = 2))
##print(index1)

if index1<2:
    print(index_clk(any_six = anysix, index_pos = hr2, index = index2, timelist = sortime, y = 9))
else:
    print(index_clk(any_six = anysix, index_pos = hr2, index = index2, timelist = sortime, y = 3))

sortime.append(":")

print(index_clk(any_six = anysix, index_pos = min1, index = index3, timelist = sortime, y = 5))

print(index_clk(any_six = anysix, index_pos = min2, index = index4, timelist = sortime, y = 9))
sortime.append(":")

print(index_clk(any_six = anysix, index_pos = sec1, index = index5, timelist = sortime, y = 5))

print(index_clk(any_six = anysix, index_pos = sec2, index = index6, timelist = sortime, y = 9))

for i in sortime:
    print(i, end = "")
```

I can achieve the DD-MM HH:MM format using if-else as above. Out of curiosity, if the above can be achieved using some datetime objects and formatting in python to simplify the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could just match it to a regular expression, fitting the date formatting:

```
if re.match(r"^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\ [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}", testString):
    print('it is in "DD-MM HH:MM" format')
```

But this will only check format, not if the date is valid, for that just give it to datetime, either after or before checking the format:

```
from datetime import datetime
try:
    date = datetime.strptime(testString, "%d-%m %H:%M")
except ValueError:
    print("Incorrect format or invalid date")
```

Beware that ValueError will both be raised for incorect format and "wrong" dates like month 13, so if you want different handling, first check formatting, like with the regular expression.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually a lot simpler:

```
import datetime, random

dates = []
for _ in range(3):
    dates.append([random.randint(0, 9) for x in range(6)])
print(dates)

try:
    for i, date in enumerate(dates):
        dates[i] = datetime.datetime(year=date[0], month=date[1], day=date[2], hour=date[3], minute=date[4], second=date[5])
    print(max(dates))

except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
```

The print in the `except` will print what was the problem with a date. If all dates were generated correctly then it will print which of them is the maximum.
You do not have to send them to `datetime.datetime` using explicit parameters, I just used it to show what is the order of the parameters it accepts.